# Pygame - Rendering Sprites At Some Certain Time

Tags: python, time, pygame, sprite, render

I have been working on this pygame application, that is bascially a coin collecting game. It has a very simple idea, where you have a freely moving player (a blue ball in this case, move it by "WASD") and it should collect coins that appear on the screen after a certain amount of time. The code is pretty long, for SO standarts, I will try my best explaining my problem.

```
from pygame.locals import *
import pygame
import sys
import time
import random

image_resources = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/Pygame App/app_resources/image_resources/"
sound_resources = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/Pygame App/app_resources/sound_resources/"

width,height = 400,400
size = (width,height)

elapsed_seconds = 0

def quit_game():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit("System exit.")

class GetSource:
    def background(self,image):
        return pygame.image.load(image_resources + image).convert()
    def player(self,image):
        return pygame.image.load(image_resources + image).convert_alpha()

class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,color,x,y,width,height):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((width,height))
        self.image.fill(pygame.color.Color(color))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,image):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_resources + image).convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class Coin(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,image):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_resources + image).convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("PyGame App")
background = GetSource().background("bg_solid_black_square.jpg")
player = GetSource().player("ball_blue.png")
player_dimension = player.get_width()

x,y = width/2-player_dimension,height/2-player_dimension
movex,movey = 0,0

walls = pygame.sprite.Group()
players = pygame.sprite.Group()
coins = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

wall_1 = Wall("white", 0, 0, width, 5)
wall_2 = Wall("white", 0, 0, 5, height)
wall_3 = Wall("white", 0, height-5, width, 5)
wall_4 = Wall("white", width-5, 0, 5, height)
player = Player("ball_blue.png")
coin = Coin("coin.png")

walls.add(wall_1,wall_2,wall_3,wall_4)
players.add(player)
coins.add(coin)
all_sprites.add(wall_1,wall_2,wall_3,wall_4,player)

while True:

    time.sleep(0.01)

    elapsed_seconds += 0.01

    collide_list_1 = pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(wall_1,players)
    collide_list_2 = pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(wall_2,players)
    collide_list_3 = pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(wall_3,players)
    collide_list_4 = pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(wall_4,players)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            quit_game()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_q:
                quit_game()
            elif event.key == K_a:
                movex = -1
            elif event.key == K_d:
                movex = 1
            elif event.key == K_w:
                movey = -1
            elif event.key == K_s:
                movey = 1

        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_a or event.key == K_d:
                movex = 0
            if event.key == K_w or event.key == K_s:
                movey = 0

    if collide_list_1 != None:
        movey = 0
        y += 1
    if collide_list_2 != None:
        movex = 0
        x += 1
    if collide_list_3 != None:
        movey = 0
        y -= 1
    if collide_list_4 != None:
        movex = 0
        x -= 1
    else:    
        x += movex
        y += movey

    player.rect.x = x
    player.rect.y = y

    coin.rect.x = random.randint(0,width)
    coin.rect.y = random.randint(0,height)

    screen.blit(background, (0,0))

    if elapsed_seconds % 4 == 0:
        coins.draw(screen)
        coins.update()

    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    all_sprites.update()

    pygame.display.update()
```

As you can see, I am increasing the "elapsed_seconds" variable every frame by the time a wait, in order the regulate frames per second, then check if it is a multiple of 4. But the thing is, when I monitored the "elapsed_seconds" variable, it never actually becomes 4. It generally goes around at "2,9998999128999" and stuff. I tried;

```
elapsed_seconds = math.floor(elapsed_seconds)
```

but that is no good as well. So, how can I render this coin at every set time interval?

EDIT: I want the sprites not to be flashing on the screen, I want them to be staying where they are after the "certin amount of time" is passed. So it should look as if it moved, after that "certain amount of time"! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `pygame.time.get_ticks()` will return elapsed milliseconds since your game started. Your method is not accurate as it does not take into account the time spent executing your game loop.

You could just track the elapsed time since you last added a coin. Then:

```
ticks = pygame.time.get_ticks()
if ticks - last_coin_ticks > 1000: # new coin once per second
    last_coin_ticks = ticks
    # add a new coin
```

Comment: Got it working perfectly. Now I will add collision detection between the coin and the player. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Oh and, the thing is, I got it working but I have a slight problem. The coins just flash on to the screen, disappearing after a blink of an eye! Since the rendering is not being done every loop, it then removes the sprite form the screen when "pygame.display.update()" is called. But I want them to stay where they are after the other one pops up. I guess this was something important to note on the question itself, since the approach might differ. Have any ideas about fixing this? Thanks :)

Comment: You should draw the coins every frame, but add a new coin to your list of coin sprites via the timer.